# "Quick Sort works well on small arrays of data, but merge sort is better for large arrays"

Tags: arrays, sorting, quicksort, mergesort

When comparing quick sort to other sorts I have heard something along the lines of "quick sort works well for small amounts of data".

And an example of this comment is here:

> Merge sort can work well on any type of data sets irrespective of its size (either large or small). whereas Quick sort cannot work well with large datasets.
>
> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort-vs-merge-sort

Specifically, I am looking at mergesort vs quicksort and have heard several times "quicksort is better for small amounts of data, and mergesort is better for large amounts of data"

I understand quick sort has its advantages over merge sort as well for larger amounts of data (locality of reference, no extra space needed, etc.).

However, I am struggling to understand why quicksort would be especially good/better than mergesort for smaller amounts of data.

**My work:**

From a quick program on my part (which is far from optimized running the basic versions of each sort) this seemed to hold true:

**For array of size 10:**

```
Merge comparisons: 34
Quicksort comparisons: 17
```

**For array of size 100:**

```
Merge sort comparisons: 672
Quicksort comparisons: 1448
```

It appears at least for number of comparisons, this is true.

However, for the life of me, I can't think of why quicksort would excel in smaller dataset, but be beaten out by mergesort in larger data sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quicksort with little or no code to avoid worst case behavior is generally faster than merge sort for random numbers (although in this case, radix sort would be faster still). On a processor with 16 registers, such as a PC in 64 bit mode, a 4 way merge sort (using nested if else instead of a heap) is about the same speed or faster than quicksort for any data.

You need to consider more than the comparisons. In general, merge sort does more moves but fewer compares than quicksort. An example where this helps merge sort to be faster is sorting an array of pointers to strings, where the time to move pointers is much faster than comparing strings.

Both quicksort and merge sort run times can be improved by using insertion sort for small sub-arrays, from about 32 to 128 elements.